# How can I append to an elements HTML with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a DIV containing text.  Previously I just tried setting new HTML like this:

```
 $("#exp").html(" - " + data.exp);
```

Now I want to add some HTML to the end of the HTML within another DIV. Is this possible with jQuery?

Comment: [You didn't search for `jquery append html`](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=jquery+append+html), did you?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But without showing us your html, and defining what you want more clearly I have no idea how to help you do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazingly, there is a method called [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), which does exactly what you want.

Answer (score -2):

you can append or prepend

```
$("#exp").append("your text here will be added after the selector");
$("#exp").prepend("you text here will be added before the selector");
```

if you want the inner HTML you can do that

```
$("#exp").html($("#exp").html() + " - " + data.exp);
```

Comment: *your text here will be added after the selector*: NO, it will be added **inside** the selected element(s). `.after()` adds the content *after* the selected element(s). The first and last line of your code will have the same result. The last just does some unnecessary processing.